How to pass Azure VM public ip address (created by Terraform) to Ansible?
I have a main.tf file which created my Azure VM and a Virtualbox Ubuntu VM for configuring the Azure VM.
data "azurerm_public_ip" "vm-publicip" {
  name                = azurerm_public_ip.public.name
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.main.name
}

output "vm-publicip" {
  value = data.azurerm_public_ip.vm-publicip.ip_address
}

Can you advise how to automatically pass the public IP address of the Azure VM to Ansible on the Virtualbox VM so that it could automatically configure the Azure VM?
I suppose a viable solution might be running Terraform also on the Ubuntu VM but is there any option that might be used?

You could use a terraform_data resource to write the result into a file, but without any code it's hard to give an answer.

What is the file name in which you need the IP address?

What CI/CD tool do you use?

Based on the code from the question, I would suggest using the terraform_data resource. You would then do something like the following:
data "azurerm_public_ip" "vm-publicip" {
  name                = azurerm_public_ip.public.name
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.main.name
}

resource "terraform_data" "ansible" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "echo ${data.azurerm_public_ip.vm-publicip.ip_address} >> /etc/ansible/hosts"
  }
}

output "vm-publicip" {
  value = data.azurerm_public_ip.vm-publicip.ip_address
}


Thanks, I am also experimenting with adding locals and environment, but why I try running it, instead of writing the value of the variables to the files, the output is simply "$VM $IP".
  my_ip=data.azurerm_public_ip.vm-publicip.ip_address
  my_vm="[azure_vm]"
}
resource "terraform_data" "inventory" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
      environment = {
      VM=local.my_vm
      IP=local.my_ip
    }
  command = "echo $VM $IP > ansible_inventory"
  }


Can you try with "echo $$VM $$IP > ansible_inventory"?

I have tried it but it just writes $$IP in the file.
I am under Windows, could that be the issue?

Well, you tell me. :D How would you read env vars otherwise in Windows?

Yeah, realized that     command = "echo %VM%  > ansible_inventory does work  :D
My only issue now is that I cannot pass the public ip address
locals {   my_ip=data.azurerm_public_ip.vm-publicip.ip_address } does not seem to store the value, at least command = "echo %IP%  > ansible_inventory actually writes %IP% instead of the value.
